# Error message when executing WindRiver workbench - host: Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, java, wind-river-workbench

I am trying to execute the WindRiver workbench on my host.
However, it crashed and the log file as shown in the following.

The java version currently installed on my computer:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I suspect this is caused by the version of Java.

Please let me know if you know how to fix it

```
ON 2015-08-25 18:56:33.830 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130131-0800/WB20141023-0742
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-08-25 18:57:02.301
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.windriver.core.runtime.jni.Env.setEnv(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at com.windriver.core.runtime.jni.Env.setEnv(Native Method)
    at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WREnv.setSystemEnv(WREnv.java:805)
    at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.initWorkbenchEnvironment(WRInstallRegistry.java:631)
    at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.init(WRInstallRegistry.java:484)
    at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.getInstance(WRInstallRegistry.java:550)
    at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.checkPreconditions(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:148)
    at com.windriver.ide.application.CopyOfIDEApplication.start(CopyOfIDEApplication.java:136)
    at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.access$2(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:1)
    at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.start(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WRWBMain.main(WRWBMain.java:37)
!SESSION 2015-08-25 18:57:09.758-----------------------------------------------
```

I suspect this is because my Workbench is 32 bit while my host is 64 bit.

Any feedback please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **WAS** getting the same error with WorkBench. I'm also running on Ubuntu 14.x 64-bit.

*It seems that packages were removed between Ubuntu 13.x and 14.x.*

I installed these packages and my WorkBench now loads:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev
sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install libxpm4:i386
sudo apt-get install libuuid1:i386
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error on Arch Linux 64 bit.

The problem lies in:

```
/<workbench_install_dir>/workbench-<your_version>/wrwb/wrworkbench/eclipse/plugins/com.windriver.core.runtime.jni_3.3.0.20110216-1702.jar
```

which needs the platform specific version (in this case linux) `com.windriver.core.runtime.jni.linux_3.3.0.20110216-1702.jar` (found in the same directory).
Unpacking the linux specific jar will reveal the library "libstdutil.so". This library needs to be checked for missing dependencies and the missing 32bit libraries installed.

Example:

```
mkdir /tmp/wbtmp && cd /tmp/wbtmp
jar -xf /home/testuser/workbench/workbench-3.3/wrwb/wrworkbench/eclipse/plugins/com.windriver.core.runtime.jni.linux_3.3.0.20110216-1702.jar
cd os/linux/x86/
ldd libstdutil.so
```

The output of the ldd command needs to be inspected for any libraries marked as "not found" and those libraries installed. In my case I was missing libpangox-1.0.so.0.

Comment: If your system does not have `jar` installed, it is probably easier to install `unzip` instead as this will also unpack jar files.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this because they are using an old WindRiver system on CentOS 7, you may need do do this:

- As per @bogdan-paun's answer, confirm that you are missing libpangox-1.0.so.0
- Download the source RPM for pangox-compat
- Use the CentOS `mock` tool (download the version from centos-extra and NOT the one from EPEL) to build a 32-bit version of this library (centos-7-i386 root)
- On your CentOS 7 system, install the pangox-compat i686 RPM that you just built
- Now your WindRiver WorkBench system should work.